# Update table with sequelize only if a value is provided (node js)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I receive a data object from the front end like so:

```
module.exports.myModule = async (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body.data  
}
```

For instance, that object contains the following properties and values:

> ```
> name : Michel,
> age: 56,
> city: Paris,
> ```

If I want to update my table, I can do:

```
myTable.update(data);
```

But, if one of the property is empty, the corresponding value in the database will become empty to.

Is there a way to update the row only if a value is provided, and keep the old value if not?

Answer (score 0):

It only validates the data before saving to the database, use the 'options : object' that are used in the 'save' of the data.
see more information here: [https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#instance-method-save](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#instance-method-save)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
let updateValues={};
if (body.name) updateValues.name  = body.name ;
if (body.age) updateValues.age= body.age;
if (body.city) updateValues.city= body.city;

myTable.update(updateValues);
```

now only entered values in body will be updated

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I had a reasonably hard time trying to reproduce this. Once I could, I had to make some assumptions that I'll hope are correct.

Assumptions made:

- You are receiving JSON from the front end (`Content-Type: application/json`)
- You are using Express according to the Question's tagging. So I assume you're using `express.json()` to offload the `data` received to the `req.body`.
- However, to the best of my (limited) knowledge, `express.json()` won't let you get away with any `undefined` value (`Unexpected token 'u'...`) AND if you don't send a property, Sequelize won't update it (e.g.: `name : Michel` will only update the `name` column, whereas `name : Michel, age: 56` will only update those two)...
- Due to the last assumption just above, the only way I was able to reproduce the issue was if the front end sends a property with a value of `null` (in which case, I would seriously consider some extra front end previous validation, but I understand that may not be smth you can control)
- Additionally, it's very likely that some of these columns in your db may have NOT NULL constraint (`allowNull: false` in Sequelize), which will basically trigger a constraint violation error.

Well, supposing those assumptions are correct, Sequelize makes it really easy to avoid trouble. :)

Please take a brief look [here in the docs](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-update).

**FTR, they make it very easy to navigate it, from the home page, you just choose `API References` and choose the version in question (stable now is v6), and then on the menu of the left you choose the class/interface/matter you're concerned with. In our case we're dealing with Models, so just click on Model and all of its methods explained will appear. This is just in case you or anyone else is interested in learning to navigate them, as it might be intimidating at first.*

In our case, the one that concerns us is `options.fields`, which should be an array, and the key here: *it 'defaults to **all** fields'*.

Meaning if you specify here that you only want to update one or two fields, no matter what kind of strange object they send you, only those will be updated. (Don't worry about receiving any other invalid property, as Sequelize is smart enough to only update values to valid column names.)

What this means is now, you'll just need to populate an array with the keys that were actually received in your `data` object.

Happy path version would be just:

```js
const { data } = req.body
console.log(data) // {"data":{"name : "Michel", "age": 56}}
const fields = Object.keys(data)
console.log(fields) // ['name', 'age']
// and then you pass fields to the options object
```

And then you're good to go. But actually that is 1) unnecessary, as Sequelize will make sure to only update the attribs provided, and 2) doesn't solve our problem, as if we receive a `null` value, its key will still be passed down to `options.fields`. And furthermore, because of the way `body-parser` works, `null` will passed as `'null'` string.

Therefore, we will need to only pass those that are not `'null'`. Unquestionably, there are diff ways to do this. Just one of them:

```js
const { data } = req.body
console.log(data) // {"data":{"name": "null", "city": "Rome"}}
const fields = []
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data)){
  if (v && v !== 'null') {
    fields.push(k)
  }
}
console.log(fields) // [ 'city' ]
// and then you pass fields to the options object
```

So, more or less, this is how it would look:

```js
function(req, res){
  const { data } = req.body
  const fields = []
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data)){
    if (v && v !== 'null') {
      fields.push(k)
    }
  }
  <Your_Model>.update(data, {
    where: {
      id: req.params.id // also assuming you passed id
      // but anyway, this is where you specify any condition
    },
    fields // or 'fields: fields', whichever syntax you prefer
  }.then( ... )
  // or await above, etc.
}
```

*Note: do take into account that, should it be possible that they send you a null value for the `data` object, you may need to do some extra previous validation to see it's not null, and if so, just not perform the update at all.*

Hope that helps. Also, if I had any misunderstanding, please feel free to point it out as it will help me learn.